# Anti de Sitter & de Sitter Spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, cosmological-constant, anti-de-sitter-spacetime, de-sitter-spacetime

Can anyone please explain what are the Anti de Sitter and de Sitter spacetime and what is special about them? I am learning general relativity and I stumbled upon them a few times, even on the subject of Schwarzschild Black Holes.

Comment: Have you tried reading the wikipedia pages for both geometries?

Comment: Why the downvote? Consider them as ngatively curved spaces. Two object on this space(time) will accelerate away from each other (like galaxies do in our universe).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minkowski space vs De Sitter Space](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/494548/)